# JOOMLA 3.X, how to edit module in backend and show in frontend

Tags: module, joomla3.0

I am bit new to Joomla. I am required to design a module which does some editing in backend and shows the output in frontend. Take a instance of user-input. I am required to take the user-input only in backend and I have to show it in frontend.

I have already developed a module for that, but it ask for user input in front-end. I need to take that input only from administrators in backend and show the output to users in frontend.

Any ideas for doing that??

Comment: Thanks for being so specific in the problem you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, check how basic system module work. Look at the code under /modules. You can learn a lot from there.

Basically you can define in your xml some parameters / input fields and stuff. Example from mod_banners

```
                <field
                name="header_text"
                type="textarea"
                filter="safehtml"
                rows="3"
                cols="40"
                label="MOD_BANNERS_FIELD_HEADER_LABEL"
                description="MOD_BANNERS_FIELD_HEADER_DESC" />
```

Then in your module php files, you can get the value saved with:

`$params->get('header_text')`

Also make sure you are not [confusing a module with a component.](http://docs.joomla.org/Extension_types_%28general_definitions%29)

For more info check:

[Joomla! Developers](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers)

[Creating a Module for Joomla 2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Module_for_Joomla_2.5)

Comment: so this xml file should be defined in the /administrator/modules/mod_my-module-name ? or should it be defined in /modules/mod_my-module-name? I mean, how could I expect the joomla to understand which part of module I am installing (adminitrative/public)? I am sorry that I don't know much concepts of joomla right now

Comment: See the updated answer. The output of the module is public (in a template position). The configuration is in administrator.

Comment: Got it. It need just some modifications in the module file. Thanks for fast reply